# 404 error accessing local IIS on Windows, access from other clients is fine

Tags: windows, iis

I ran into a weird error where I could not browse to the local server's install of IIS using either http://localhost or the domain name of the server.   I would always get a 404 error.

I could access the server from other workstations without a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Binding on the Default Web Site.   Someone had set the binding on port 80 to be a specific IP address.   This meant that the server ignored requests from localhost, 127.0.0.1, etc...